# Why might Python's `from` form of an import statement bind a module name?

Tags: python, import

I have a Python project with the following structure:

```
testapp/
├── __init__.py
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils.py
└── utils.py
```

All of the modules are empty except `testapp/api/__init__.py` which has the following code:

```
from testapp import utils

print "a", utils

from testapp.api.utils import x

print "b", utils
```

and `testapp/api/utils.py` which defines `x`:

```
x = 1
```

Now from the root I import `testapp.api`:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.
$ python -c "import testapp.api"
a <module 'testapp.utils' from 'testapp/utils.pyc'>
b <module 'testapp.api.utils' from 'testapp/api/utils.pyc'>
```

The result of the import surprises me, because it shows that the second `import` statement has overwritten `utils`. Yet the docs state that the [from statement will not bind a module name](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> The from form does not bind the module name: it goes through the list
>   of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in step
>   (1), and binds the name in the local namespace to the object thus
>   found.

And indeed, when in a terminal I use a `from ... import ...` statement, no module names are introduced:

```
>>> from os.path import abspath
>>> path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

I suspect this has to do with Python, at the time of the second import statement, trying to import `testapp.api.utils` which refers to `testapp.utils` and failing but I'm not certain.

What is happening here?

Comment: I would not have expected this behavior and I'm eager to hear the answer as well.

Comment: can you add some code from the various utils files?

Comment: @NikosM. as I mentioned, all of the other files are empty.

Comment: yes i see, you will have to use `from module.name import property as alias` structure to avoid namespace colissions, as the local namespace is the same for your init file

Comment: The example would be clearer if `testapp/utils.py` (and the first two nonempty lines in `testapp/api/__init__.py`) were removed.  They're not essential to the question and just serve as distractors.

Comment: No, they are essential to the question. The question is why `utils` is overwritten when the second import statement is executed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [import system documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs,
>   the `import` or **`import-from`** statements, or built-in `__import__()`)
>   a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule
>   object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after
>   importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is
>   bound to the submodule. Let’s say you have the following directory
>   structure:
>
> ```
> spam/
>     __init__.py
>     foo.py
>     bar.py
> ```
>
> and `spam/__init__.py` has the following lines in it:
>
> ```
> from .foo import Foo
> from .bar import Bar
> ```
>
> then executing the following puts a name binding to `foo` and `bar` in
>   the `spam` module:
>
> ```
> >>> import spam
> >>> spam.foo
> <module 'spam.foo' from '/tmp/imports/spam/foo.py'>
> >>> spam.bar
> <module 'spam.bar' from '/tmp/imports/spam/bar.py'>
> ```
>
> Given Python’s familiar name binding rules this might seem surprising,
>   but it’s actually a fundamental feature of the import system. The
>   invariant holding is that if you have `sys.modules['spam']` and
>   `sys.modules['spam.foo']` (as you would after the above import), the
>   latter must appear as the `foo` attribute of the former.

If you do `from testapp.api.utils import x`, the import statement will not load `utils` into the local namespace. However, the import machinery *will* load `utils` into the `testapp.api` namespace, to make further imports work right. It just happens that in your case, `testapp.api` is also the local namespace, so you're getting a surprise.

Comment: did not downvote, but can you explain more, it is not clear to me

Comment: If you use the `from` form, no names are imported into the local namespace. You're saying they're bound anyway if they refer to something though? If that were true, then `path = 1; from os.path import abspath; path` should not evaluate to `1`.

Comment: @CeasarBautista: The module name is not bound in the *local* namespace, but it *is* bound in the package's namespace. It's just that in this case, those are the same namespace.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you remember how you can upon this? Is it in the docs somewhere?

Comment: @CeasarBautista: Doc reference added. I couldn't find the Python 2 version, so I've linked the Python 3 version, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: It's important to emphasize that the namespaces are identical only because this is occurring inside `__init__.py`.  If this were any module other than that, this behavior would not occur.