# Unknown python import behaviour from relative package

Tags: python, import

I've stumbled across some odd python (2.7) import behaviour, which, whilst easy to work around, has me scratching my head.

Given the following folder structure:

```
test/
    __init__.py
    x.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        x.py
```

Where test/package/__init__.py contains the following

```
from .. import x
print x
from .x import hello
print x
print x.hello
```

And test/package/x.py contains the following

```
hello = 1
```

Why would running `import test.package` from a REPL result in the following output?

```
<module 'test.x' from 'test/x.pyc'>
<module 'test.package.x' from 'test/package/x.pyc'>
1
```

I would have expected `x` to reference the top level `x` module, however what the second import does instead, is to import the whole local `x` module (not just `hello` as I expected), effectively trampling on the first import.

Can anyone explain the mechanics of the import here?

Comment: What makes you think the first import brought in one `x` and the second replaced it with a different `x`? There's nothing in your code or description that tests or demonstrates that.

Comment: actually I think OP is right

Comment: @AnttiHaapala he could be, but he hasn't actually tested that (e.g., by `print x` before and after the second `import`)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974455/why-might-pythons-the-from-form-of-an-import-statement-bind-a-module-name

Comment: abarnert, when I alter the code to add a print before the second import, it does highlight the expected module is imported

FIRST: <module 'test.x' from 'test/x.pyc'>
SECOND: <module 'test.package.x' from 'test/package/x.pyc'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from .x import name` realizes that `test.package.x` needs to be a module. It then checks the corresponding entry in `sys.modules`; if it is found there, then `sys.modules['test.package.x'].hello` is imported into the calling module.

However, if `sys.modules['test.package.x']` does not exist yet, the module is loaded; and as the last step of loading the `sys.modules['test.package'].x` is set to point to the newly loaded module, even if you explicitly did not ask for it. Thus the second import overrides the name of the first import.

This is by design, otherwise

```
import foo.bar.baz
foo.bar.baz.x()
```

and

```
from foo.bar import baz
baz.x()
```

wouldn't be interchangeable.

---

I am unable to find good documentation on this behaviour in the Python 2 documentation, but the [Python 3 behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) is essentially the same in this case:

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs, the `import` or `import`-`from` statements, or built-in  `__import__()`) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule.
>
> *[...]*
>
> The invariant holding is that if you have `sys.modules['spam']` and `sys.modules['spam.foo']` (as you would after the above import), the latter must appear as the `foo` attribute of the former.